# Native sources in the JDK src.zip

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have openjdk-8-source installed on my system (Ubuntu 16.04). I have unzipped the `src.zip`, however I cannot seem to find the sources for a lot of the native methods (specifically `sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl#lock0`). Does anyone know where it is located in the `src.zip`? I've looked in multiple places, and even tried looking for the source files by extension, but nothing turned up.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this path `jdk/src/solaris/native/sun/nio/ch/FileDispatcherImpl.c`

https://github.com/keerath/openjdk-8-source/blob/master/jdk/src/solaris/native/sun/nio/ch/FileDispatcherImpl.c